# Access StackExchange data using LinqPad

Tags: .net, linqpad

I am wondering if there is a way to access StackExchange data from LinqPad without downloading the dump.

I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218195/how-to-query-stack-exchange-in-linqpad) post around the same lines, but solution suggested there, is not working any more.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

TIA.

Comment: The OData endpoint was deprecated a while ago, and seems to have been removed now.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque : Just curious. Is there any other way?

Comment: @DarkKnight, yes, the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque : But, can that be used as datasource for LinqPad? OP seems to be looking for access through LinqPad  as datasource.

Comment: @DarkKnight I don't think so, at least not directly. But there might be a .NET library to access it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on meta